# Capturar, en un único punto, todo lo enviado al cliente desde "express.js"

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express

¿Cómo puedo capturar **toda** la salida que se haga a través del objeto `res` del `express` para *loguearlo*, guardarlo o intervenirlo? Por ejemplo, en una aplicación que usa módulos que ponen sus propios `middlewares`, como ***passport.js***.

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express();

// capture_all_res(app, 'guardar.txt')

app.listen(3000);

app.get('/uno',function(req,res){
    res.send('algo');
});

app.get('/dos',function(req,res){
    res.header('Content-Type','text/plain');
    res.end('otra cosa');
});
```

Sería bueno hacer un `pipe` o mandarlo a un archivo o a una función que capture cada salida.

## Cosas que no solucionan el problema:

1. Agregar un `console.log` en cada `res.send` o `res.write`. Hay módulos que escribo yo y además que escribieron otros (que también escriben en `res`), como ***passport.js*** y no sería correcto intervenirlos.
2. Plantear capturar el requerimiento con algo tipo, porque eso me permite capturar el `req`, salvo que pueda acá hacerle algo al `res` para que las sucesivas llamadas use a `use/get` (si usan el mismo objeto `res`)
   ya estén capturadas:

   ```
   app.use('*', (req, res, next) => {
     // hacer algo
     next();
   });
   ```
3. Usar http://github.com/expressjs/morgan y otros *request-loggers*

Comment: osea, quieres poder mediante una función, middleware o cualquier otra herramienta, capturar el argumento de todos los res.send() en tu aplicación y en conjuntos los de los módulos que también lo utilicen ?

Comment: No sé si eso alcanza. Porque se pueden enviar datos al cliente a través de varias funciones seguro `send` y `write`, pero también quizás `end`, y las funciones que envían los headers. Lo que quisiera capturar es el flujo de los caracteres que se están enviando al cliente

Comment: La única opción válida que se me ocurre: **reemplazar** los métodos relevantes en `response`, creando un *middleware* para usar **el primero de todos**. Esta pregunta [express.js - how to intercept response.send() / response.json()](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33732509) te puede venir bien.

Comment: Gracias. Parece que el camino puede estar por ahí.

Comment: @Dolmenes, podrías crear una respuesta en Español usando como guía de referencia el enlace que has compartido.

Comment: @EmilioPlatzer ¿haz revisado la respuesta de ArtEze? ¿Haz encontrado otra solución por tu cuenta?

Comment: Hola, como comenté en el otro post. Estoy justo en este momento probando un par de soluciones. Hasta ahroa ninguna contesta exactamente la pregunta. Voy a avisar cuál es la que más se acerca en un par de horas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Capturar toda la salida express

¿Toda?, No sé, no puedo demostrarlo. Pero no encontré problemas con las pruebas que hice y la forma es sencilla. Basta con interceptar la función `_writeRaw` para llamar a cualquier función en el lugar de `procesarLoCapturado`

```
app.use(function(req,res,next){
    res.originales={_writeRaw:res._writeRaw};
    console.log('res.originales',res._send);
    res._writeRaw = function _writeRaw(data, encoding, cb){
        procesarLoCapturado(data);
        return res.originales._writeRaw.apply(res, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
    };
    next();
});
```

### Ejemplo completo

Acá va un ejemplo con llamadas a `send` `write` `setHeader`.

```
"use strict";

var express = require('express')
var app = express()
var fs = require('fs');

app.use(function(req,res,next){
    res.originales={_writeRaw:res._writeRaw};
    console.log('res.originales',res._send);
    res._writeRaw = function _writeRaw(data, encoding, cb){
        fs.appendFileSync('res.log',data);
        return res.originales._writeRaw.apply(res, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
    };
    next();
});

app.get('/hola.txt', function (req, res) {
    res.send('<b>Hola</b> Mundo textual!')
})

app.get('/hola.html', function (req, res) {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
    res.write('<b>Hola</b> Mundo hipervinculado!');
    res.end();
})

app.use(express.static('public'))

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!')
})
```

Este ejemplo crea un archivo res.log donde se van poniendo todos los bytes enviados del servidor al cliente. Lo probé con el chrome poniendo:

```
localhost:3000/hola.txt

localhost:3000/hola.html

localhost:3000/inexistente.txt
```

Y repitiendo las llamadas (para que me de 304 cuando corresponde). No tuve problemas con las pruebas de concepto. Falta probarlo en un proyecto grande.

Comment: -1 - No me parece correcto responde uno su pregunta mas aun cuando hay una recompensa de por medio.

Comment: @fwBasic stackoverflow no es un jueguito por puntos, es un lugar donde pedir ayuda y compartir conocimiento. ¿Sabías que el que ofrece una recompensa puede elegir a quién otorgarla? (puede no ser la respuesta aceptada, debe aceptar la solución que más lo satisfaga a él) ¿Sabías que stackoverflow te puede dar una medalla por contestar tu propia pregunta? ¿Sabías que se puede proponer en "meta" cambiar las reglas de stackoverflow para no permitir cosas incorrectas? (si todos están de acuerdo con ese punto de vista). ¿Votar en contra de una pregunta sin opinar que no es útil te parece correcto?

Comment: Entiendo tu molestia como también entiendo el funcionamiento de SO, tal vez si no hubieses puesto una recompensa mi punto seria positivo.

Comment: No estoy molesto. No sabía cuan informado estabas. La recompensa no la puse yo. No creo que uno se pueda auto asignar una recompensa y si se pudiera habría que cambiar SO para que no se pueda

Comment: Bueno, bueno... esta bien, confiare en tu palabra, te quitare el -1... ;))... ya contento?

Comment: Acercando el mouse a la recompensa ofrecida te dice quién la ofreció

Answer (score 2):

Para capturar todos los valores, lo que hice fue publicar en el servidor local un archivo de texto que contiene, lo más aproximado posible, todos los valores de la variable `res`, es decir, hice una recreación del objeto mediante un string.

Para recrear el objeto, fue necesario **podar**, ya que es un objeto circular... No creo que sea posible obtener el objeto exacto, pero se puede ir generando recursivamente hasta un nivel dado (en mi caso le puse nivel 3).

Luego de haber podado el objeto y publicado en el servidor local, se va mostrando en consola, mientras se descarga el archivo, que vendría a ser una cadena de caracteres, que si se prueba con `eval` debería convertirse en objeto.

El único problema es que para navegar por el objeto, haciendo `capturado.propiedad_ejemplo`, es necesario descargarlo síncronamente, de tal modo que luego se pueda meter en una variable.

Ya intenté mostrar en la consola luego de varios segundos de haberla descargado, pero solo se muestra una sección del objeto, porque al parecer la descarga es un *buffer*, y no se puede meter completo. Por esto, creo que otra solución sería guardar la variable `chunk` en algún archivo y luego cargar el archivo en una variable.

Descomentando las líneas en la función `capturar_todo`, se puede ir al navegador web, en la dirección `localhost:3000/capturado`, va a aparecer una página vacía, pero se puede tocar *F12* para ir a la consola *Javascript* y tipear `capturado`. Por ahora es la única manera que tengo de navegar por el objeto.

Nota: La función para saber si una función es nativa del sistema, la saqué de [aquí](http://www.elwebmaster.com/general/detectar-nativa-javascript).

Código *Node JS*:

```
//Primera parte del código: Se poda crea el servidor y se publica el objeto podado.

var express = require('express')
var app = express();

app.listen(3000);

function esFuncionNativa(funcion) {
    return (/\{\s*\[native code\]\s*\}/).test('' + funcion);
}
function podar(objeto,nivel)
{
    if(nivel)
    {
        var salida=""
        salida+="{"+"\n"
        for(var i in objeto)
        {
            try {
                var cadenizado=JSON.stringify(objeto[i])
                if(cadenizado==undefined)
                {
                    var esNativa=esFuncionNativa(objeto[i])
                    if(esNativa)
                    {
                        salida+=i+": function(){return \"La funcion es nativa\"}"
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        salida+=i+": "+objeto[i]
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    salida+=i+": "+cadenizado
                }
            } catch (err) {
                try {
                    salida+=i+": "+podar(objeto[i],nivel-1)
                } catch (err) {
                    salida+=i+": "+"'Algo ha fallado.',"+"\n"
                }
            }
            salida+=",\n"
        }
        salida+="fin: \"\""+"\n"
        salida+="}"
        return salida
    }
    else
    {
        return "'Ha llegado al límite del nivel.'"
    }
}

function capturar_todo(req, res) {
    var salida=""
    //var salida+="<script>"
    //salida+="capturado="
    salida+=podar(res,3)
    //salida+="</script>"
    res.send( salida );
}

var enviado=app.get('/capturado', capturar_todo);

//Segunda parte del código: Muestra en consola el objeto que se va descargando.

var http=require("http") //Para descargar el archivo generado.

var options = {
    hostname: 'localhost',
    port: 3000,
    path: '/capturado',
    method: 'GET'
};
var capturado={};
var req = http.request(options, function(res){
    res.setEncoding('utf8')
    function res_on(chunk){
        console.log(chunk)
    }
    res.on('data',res_on);
});
req.end()
```

Comment: Estoy probando esta solución y otras que encontré por ahí. En un par de horas les cuento si logré hacer andar alguna y pego el código de lo que funcione